# Does the theory of holographic superconductors have any application?

Tags: superconductivity, holographic-principle

I recently became aware of the relatively novel concept of holographic superconductors, and I was wondering whether anyone here has read something about experimental application of these theories.

Have physicists actually used some of these theories to explain findings in their lab, and if so, could someone maybe provide me with resources?

Comment: Theories should *predict* occurrences and findings, not just be a way of explaining already found things. Theories must have predictive value to be at all useful, else, they are no better than ad-hoc explanations.

Comment: There is a short section covering experimental tests in this 2016 review by Hartnoll, Lucas, and Sachdev: https://arxiv.org/abs/1612.07324. I am not an expert in this field by any means, but for my taste this section does not have a lot of detail, in particular no plots or numerical results. Make of that what you will.

Comment: @ChiralAnomaly Which is why i said "not *just*". I know most new areas in physics are started by the discovery of a strange phenomenon, such as the photoelectric effect and quantum mechanics, the Michelson-Morley experiment and the onset of relativity. My point is, a theory with little predictive valuable has little use, anyway. I think we both know what I'm referring to, but that I'm butchering how I'm saying it.

Comment: @ChemiCalChems Your point is a good one. (I missed the word "just".) I deleted my comment.